# How to GET and display data from MariaDB on Vertx page?

Tags: java, rest, jdbc, mariadb, vert.x

I currently have a simple index.html displaying sample pre-created data displaying annotation details, as well as a Add, Delete and Update function. My Add Annotation function works well, and any newly added annotations is added to the database properly (POST).

However, the problem is that I am trying to display the actual data (GET) from my database on the Vertx webpage, instead of just the sample data as mentioned above as the sample data and the actual data do not correspond.

MainVerticle.java:

```
package io.vertx.starter;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.AsyncResult;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.jdbc.JDBCClient;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.ResultSet;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLClient;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.jdbc.JDBCClient;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection;
import io.vertx.ext.sql.UpdateResult;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
import io.vertx.starter.components.BoundingBox;
import io.vertx.starter.components.Picture;


import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

//import static com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.LOGGER;


public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  private JDBCClient jdbc;
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainVerticle.class);
  private Future fut;
  private String SQL_GET_ANNOTATION = "SELECT * FROM boundingboxes";
  private String SQL_ADD_ANNOTATION = "INSERT INTO boundingboxes (picID, boxname, boxcategory, boxcolour, xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight, endX, endY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  private int nextCount = 0;
  private Map<Integer, Picture> pictures = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  private Map<Integer, BoundingBox> annotations = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  @Override
  public void start(Future<Void> fut) {

    createBBData();

    startHttpServer();

    dbConnection();

//    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
  }

  public Future<Void> dbConnection(){

        // Create a JDBC client
    jdbc = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject()
      .put("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/annotationdb")
      .put("driver_name", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
      .put("max_pool_size", 5)
      .put("user", "root"));

    jdbc.getConnection(ar -> {
      if (ar.failed()) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not open a database connection", ar.cause());
        fut.fail(ar.cause());         // If SQL Connection could not be obtained, then method future is completed to fail.
      } else {
        SQLConnection connection = ar.result(); // else ... SQL connection is established with successful AsyncResult (Use this connection to perform a SQL query)
        connection.query(SQL_GET_ANNOTATION, get -> {
          connection.close();
          if (get.failed()) {            // If SQL Query fails ...
            LOGGER.error("Database operation error", get.cause());  // ...
            fut.fail(get.cause());

          } else {
            LOGGER.info("Connection Established");
//            fut.complete();   // Complete method future object with a success
            System.out.print("Succeed");

            ResultSet rs = get.result();
            if (rs.getNumRows() > 0) {
              System.out.println(rs.getResults().toString());
              nextCount++;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return fut;
  }

  public Future<Void> startHttpServer(){
    Future<Void> future = Future.future();
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response
        .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
        .end("<h1>Hello from my first Vert.x 3 application</h1>");
    });

    // Serve static resources from the /assets directory
    router.route("/assets/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("assets"));
    router.get("/api/annotations").handler(this::getAll);
    router.route("/api/annotations*").handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.post("/api/annotations").handler(this::addOne);
    router.get("/api/whiskies/:id").handler(this::getOne);
    router.put("/api/whiskies/:id").handler(this::updateOne);
    router.delete("/api/whiskies/:id").handler(this::deleteOne);

    vertx
      .createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(router::accept)
      .listen(
        // Retrieve the port from the configuration,
        // default to 8080.
        config().getInteger("http.port", 9080)
      );

    return future;

  }

  //  private void startBackend(Handler<AsyncResult<SQLConnection>> next, Future<Void> fut) {
//    jdbc.getConnection(ar -> {
//      if (ar.failed()) {
//        fut.fail(ar.cause());
//      } else {
//        next.handle(Future.succeededFuture(ar.result()));
//      }
//    });
//  }

  private void completeStartup(AsyncResult<HttpServer> http, Future<Void> fut) {
    if (http.succeeded()) {
      fut.complete();
    } else {
      fut.fail(http.cause());
    }
  }

  private void createBBData() {
//    Picture picture1 = new Picture(1, "abstract1", "https://i2.wp.com/www.deteched.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/abstract_pyramids-2560x1440.jpg?fit=2560%2C1440", "A1");
//    pictures.put(picture1.getPicID(), picture1);
//    Picture picture2 = new Picture(2, "abstract2", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523477725095-77d6dfdafdec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80", "A2");
//    pictures.put(picture2.getPicID(), picture2);

    BoundingBox annotation1 = new BoundingBox("P1", "sign1", "signs", "Magenta", 340.0, 110.0, 100.0, 200.0, 500.0, 400.0);
    annotations.put(annotation1.getBbID(), annotation1);
    BoundingBox annotation2 = new BoundingBox("P2", "woman1", "people", "Red", 300.0, 150.0, 200.0, 400.0, 600.0, 350.0);
    annotations.put(annotation2.getBbID(), annotation2);
  }

  private void getAll(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    routingContext.response()
      .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
      .end(Json.encodePrettily(annotations.values()));
  }

  private void getOne(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    System.out.println("[TEST ] ID = " + routingContext.request().getParam("bbID"));
    final String bbID = routingContext.request().getParam("bbID");
    if (bbID == null) {
      routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end();
    } else {
      jdbc.getConnection(ar -> {
        // Read the request's content and create an instance of Whisky.
        System.out.println("CONNECTION SELECT OK");
        SQLConnection connection = ar.result();
        select(bbID, connection, result -> {
          if (result.succeeded()) {
            routingContext.response()
              .setStatusCode(200)
              .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
              .end(Json.encodePrettily(result.result()));
          } else {
            routingContext.response()
              .setStatusCode(404).end();
          }
          connection.close();
        });
      });
    }
  }

  private void addOne(RoutingContext routingContext) {  // OK
    jdbc.getConnection(ar -> {
      System.out.println("CONNECTION INSERT OK");

    final BoundingBox annotation = Json.decodeValue(routingContext.getBodyAsString(),
      BoundingBox.class);
    SQLConnection connection = ar.result();
    annotations.put(annotation.getBbID(), annotation);
    insert(annotation, connection, (r) ->

      routingContext.response()
      .setStatusCode(201)
      .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
      .end(Json.encodePrettily(r.result())));
      connection.close();
    });
  }

  private void updateOne(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    final String bbID = routingContext.request().getParam("bbID");
    JsonObject json = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
    if (bbID == null || json == null) {
      routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end();
    } else {
      jdbc.getConnection(ar ->
        update(bbID, json, ar.result(), (annotation) -> {
          if (annotation.failed()) {
            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(404).end();
          } else {
            routingContext.response()
              .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
              .end(Json.encodePrettily(annotation.result()));
          }
          ar.result().close();
        })
      );
    }
  }

  private void deleteOne(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    String bbID = routingContext.request().getParam("bbID");
    if (bbID == null) {
      routingContext.response().setStatusCode(400).end();
    } else {
      jdbc.getConnection(ar -> {
        SQLConnection connection = ar.result();
        connection.execute("DELETE FROM boundingboxes WHERE id='" + bbID + "'",
          result -> {
            routingContext.response().setStatusCode(204).end();
            connection.close();
          });
      });
    }
  }

  private void select(String bbID, SQLConnection connection, Handler<AsyncResult<BoundingBox>> resultHandler) {
    System.out.println("[TEST]  SELECT REQUEST !!!");
    connection.queryWithParams("SELECT * FROM boundingboxes", new JsonArray().add(bbID), ar -> {
      if (ar.failed()) {
        resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Annotation not found"));
      } else {
        if (ar.result().getNumRows() >= 1) {
          System.out.println(ar.result().getResults().get(0).encodePrettily());
          System.out.println(ar.result().getRows().get(0).fieldNames());
          System.out.println(ar.result().getRows().get(0).encodePrettily());

          resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new BoundingBox(ar.result().getRows().get(0))));
        } else {
          System.out.println("Annotation is not found!");
          resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Annotation not found"));
        }
      }
    });
  }

    private void insert(BoundingBox annotation, SQLConnection connection, Handler<AsyncResult<BoundingBox>> next) { // OK
      String sql = "INSERT INTO boundingboxes (picID, boxname, boxcategory, boxcolour, xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight, endX, endY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      connection.updateWithParams(sql,
        new JsonArray().add(annotation.getPicID()).add(annotation.getBoxName()).add(annotation.getBoxcategory()).add(annotation.getBoxcolour()).add(annotation.getXcoordi()).add(annotation.getYcoordi()).add(annotation.getWidth()).add(annotation.getHeight()).add(annotation.getEndX()).add(annotation.getEndX()),
        (ar) -> {
          if (ar.failed()) {
            next.handle(Future.failedFuture(ar.cause()));
            connection.close();
            return;
          }
          UpdateResult result = ar.result();
          BoundingBox bb = new BoundingBox(result.getKeys().getInteger(0), annotation.getPicID(), annotation.getBoxName(), annotation.getBoxcategory(), annotation.getBoxcolour(), annotation.getXcoordi(), annotation.getYcoordi(), annotation.getWidth(), annotation.getHeight(), annotation.getEndX(), annotation.getEndY());
          next.handle(Future.succeededFuture(bb));
        });
    }

  private void update(String bbID, JsonObject content, SQLConnection connection,
                      Handler<AsyncResult<BoundingBox>> resultHandler) {
    String sql = "UPDATE boundingboxes SET picID=?, boxname=?, boxcategory=?, boxcolour=?, xcoordi=?, ycoordi=?, boxWidth=?, boxHeight=?, endX=?, endY=? WHERE bbID=?";
    connection.updateWithParams(sql,
      new JsonArray().add(content.getString("picID")).add(content.getString("boxname")).add(content.getString("boxcategory")).add(content.getString("boxcolour")).add(content.getDouble("xcoordi")).add(content.getDouble("ycoordi")).add(content.getDouble("boxWidth")).add(content.getDouble("boxHeight")).add(content.getDouble("endX")).add(content.getDouble("endY")).add(bbID),
      update -> {
        if (update.failed()) {
          resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Cannot update the annotation"));
          return;
        }
        if (update.result().getUpdated() == 0) {
          resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Annotation not found"));
          return;
        }
        resultHandler.handle(
          Future.succeededFuture(new BoundingBox(Integer.valueOf(bbID),
            content.getString("picID"), content.getString("boxname"), content.getString("boxcategory"), content.getString("boxcolour"), content.getDouble("xcoordi"), content.getDouble("ycoordi"), content.getDouble("boxWidth"), content.getDouble("boxHeight"), content.getDouble("endX"), content.getDouble("endY"))));
      });
  }

}
```

BoundingBox.java:

```
package io.vertx.starter.components;

import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class BoundingBox {

  public double xcoordi = 0;
  public double ycoordi = 0;
  public double boxWidth = 0;
  public double boxHeight = 0;
  public double endX = 0;
  public double endY = 0;
  public final int bbID;
  public String picID;
  public String boxname;
  public String boxcategory;
  public String boxcolour;
  private static final AtomicInteger COUNTER = new AtomicInteger();

  public BoundingBox(String picID, String boxname, String boxcategory, String boxcolour, double xcoordi, double ycoordi, double boxWidth, double boxHeight, double endX, double endY) {
    this.bbID = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
    this.picID = picID;
    this.boxname = boxname;
    this.boxcategory = boxcategory;
    this.boxcolour = boxcolour;
    this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
    this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
    this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
    this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
    this.endX = endX;
    this.endY = endY;
  }

  public BoundingBox(int bbID, String picID, String boxname, String boxcategory, String boxcolour, double xcoordi, double ycoordi, double boxWidth, double boxHeight, double endX, double endY) {
    this.bbID = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
    this.picID = picID;
    this.boxname = boxname;
    this.boxcategory = boxcategory;
    this.boxcolour = boxcolour;
    this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
    this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
    this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
    this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
    this.endX = endX;
    this.endY = endY;
  }

  public BoundingBox(JsonObject json) {
    System.out.println("JSON : " + json.encodePrettily());
    this.bbID = json.getInteger("bbID");
    this.picID = json.getString("picID");
    this.boxname = json.getString("boxname");
    this.boxcategory = json.getString("boxcategory");
    this.boxcolour = json.getString("boxcolour");
    this.xcoordi = json.getDouble("xcoordi");
    this.ycoordi = json.getDouble("ycoordi");
    this.boxWidth = json.getDouble("boxWidth");
    this.boxHeight = json.getDouble("boxHeight");
    this.endX = json.getDouble("endX");
    this.endY = json.getDouble("endY");
  }

  public BoundingBox(){
    this.bbID = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
  }

  public int getBbID() {
    return bbID;
  }
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>List of Annotations</title>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" role="main">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>List of Annotations</h1>

    <p>Just an example of simple CRUD application developed using Vert.x and Vertx Web.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Annotations</h1>
    <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary annotation-add" data-action="add" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#annotationModal">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add a new annotation
    </button>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>bbID</th>
            <th>picID</th>
            <th>Box Name</th>
            <th>Box Category</th>
            <th>Box Colour</th>
            <th>X-Coordi</th>
            <th>Y-Coordi</th>
            <th>Box Width</th>
            <th>Box Height</th>
            <th>End X</th>
            <th>End Y</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="content">
          <!-- filled using Ajax -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        load();
        initModal();
    });
    function create(picID, boxname, boxcategory, boxcolour, xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight, endX, endY) {
        $.post("/api/annotations", JSON.stringify({picID: picID, boxname: boxname, boxcategory: boxcategory, boxcolour: boxcolour, xcoordi: xcoordi, ycoordi: ycoordi, boxWidth: boxWidth, boxHeight: boxHeight, endX: endX, endY: endY}), function () {
            load();
        }, "json");
    }
    function remove(bbID) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "DELETE",
            url: "/api/annotations/" + bbID
        }).done(function () {
            load();
        });
    }
    function update(bbID, picID, boxname, boxcategory, boxcolour, xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight, endX, endY) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "PUT",
            url: "/api/annotations/" + bbID,
            data: JSON.stringify({picID: picID, boxname: boxname, boxcategory: boxcategory, boxcolour: boxcolour, xcoordi: xcoordi, ycoordi: ycoordi, boxWidth: boxWidth, boxHeight: boxHeight, endX: endX, endY: endY})
        }).done(function () {
            load();
        });
    }
    function load() {
        $("#content").children().remove();
        $.getJSON("/api/annotations", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                $("<tr><td>" + val.bbID + "</td><td>" + val.picID + "</td><td>" + val.boxname + "</td><td>" + val.boxcategory + "</td><td>" + val.boxcolour + "</td><td>" + val.xcoordi + "</td><td>" + val.ycoordi + "</td><td>" + val.boxWidth + "</td><td>" + val.boxHeight + "</td><td>" + val.endX + "</td><td>" + val.endY + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                        "<button data-action='edit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm annotation-edit' " +
                        "data-toggle='modal' " +
                        "data-target='#annotationModal' " +
                        "data-bbID='" + val.bbID + "' " +
                        "data-boxname='" + val.boxname + "' " +
                        "data-boxcategory='" + val.boxcategory + "' " +
                        "data-boxcolour='" + val.boxcolour + "'>" +
                        "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" +
                        "</button>" +
                        "&nbsp;" +
                        "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm annotation-delete' data-bbID='" + val.bbID + "'>" +
                        "   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span>" +
                        "</button>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "</tr>").appendTo("#content");
            });
            initCallbacks();
        });
    }
    function initCallbacks() {
        $(".annotation-delete").unbind().click(function() {
           var bbID = $(this).data("bbID");
           remove(bbID);
        });
    }
    function initModal() {
        $("#annotationModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var action = button.data('action');
            var bbID = button.data('bbID');
            var annotationAction = $("#annotationAction");
            annotationAction.unbind();
            var modal = $(this);
            if (action === "add") {
                modal.find('.modal-title').text("Add an annotation");
                modal.find('#annotation-picID').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-boxname').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-boxcategory').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-boxcolour').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-xcoordi').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-ycoordi').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-boxWidth').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-boxHeight').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-endX').val("");
                modal.find('#annotation-endY').val("");
                annotationAction.click(function () {
                    create($("#annotation-picID").val(), $("#annotation-boxname").val(), $("#annotation-boxcategory").val(), $("#annotation-boxcolour").val(), $("#annotation-xcoordi").val(), $("#annotation-ycoordi").val(), $("#annotation-boxWidth").val(), $("#annotation-boxHeight").val(), $("#annotation-endX").val(), $("#annotation-endY").val());
                    $('#annotationModal').modal('toggle');
                });
            } else {
                modal.find('.modal-title').text("Edit an annotation");
                modal.find('#annotation-picID').val(button.data("picID"));
                modal.find('#annotation-boxname').val(button.data("boxname"));
                modal.find('#annotation-boxcategory').val(button.data("boxcategory"));
                modal.find('#annotation-boxcolour').val(button.data("boxcolour"));
                modal.find('#annotation-xcoordi').val(button.data("xcoordi"));
                modal.find('#annotation-ycoordi').val(button.data("ycoordi"));
                modal.find('#annotation-boxWidth').val(button.data("boxWidth"));
                modal.find('#annotation-boxHeight').val(button.data("boxHeight"));
                modal.find('#annotation-endX').val(button.data("endX"));
                modal.find('#annotation-endY').val(button.data("endY"));
                annotationAction.click(function () {
                    update(id, $("#annotation-picID").val(), $("#annotation-boxname").val(), $("#annotation-boxcategory").val(), $("#annotation-boxcolour").val(), $("#annotation-xcoordi").val(), $("#annotation-ycoordi").val(), $("#annotation-boxWidth").val(), $("#annotation-boxHeight").val(), $("#annotation-endX").val(), $("#annotation-endY").val());
                    $('#annotationModal').modal('toggle');
                });
            }
        })
    }
</script>
<div class="modal fade" id="annotationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="annotationModalTitle">Add an annotation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-picID" class="control-label">Pic ID:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-picID">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-boxname" class="control-label">Box Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-boxname">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-boxcategory" class="control-label">Box Category:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-boxcategory">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-boxcolour" class="control-label">Box Colour:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-boxcolour">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-xcoordi" class="control-label">X-Coordi:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-xcoordi">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-ycoordi" class="control-label">Y-Coordi:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-ycoordi">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-boxWidth" class="control-label">Box Width:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-boxWidth">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-boxHeight" class="control-label">Box Height:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-boxHeight">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-endX" class="control-label">End X:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-endX">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="annotation-endY" class="control-label">End Y:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="annotation-endY">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="annotationAction" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Database (columns):

```
picID, boxname, boxcategory, boxcolour, xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth,  boxHeight, endX, endY
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Ommitted some get and set functions from BoundingBox class due to word count limit.

Comment: When you say "do not correspond", what do you mean, actually?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin My webpage is only showing sample data already manually generated beforehand, and not the data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which GET you mean, you have two get routes:

```
router.get("/api/annotations").handler(this::getAll);
router.get("/api/whiskies/:id").handler(this::getOne);
```

1.) The first one never goes to the database, only returns the pre-initialized annotations:

```
private void getAll(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    routingContext.response()
      .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
      .end(Json.encodePrettily(annotations.values()));
  }
```

here you should create a similar db-select as you did in your getOne method, only without Ids, and return the result.

2.) The second one (/api/whiskies/:id) never gets called in your html.